# R - Selecionar elementos de um data frame com uma coluna que tem o mesmo nome de uma variável global com `dplyr`

Tags: r

Considere o seguinte `data.frame` e a variável `x`

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10)), y = 1:20)
x <- 0
```

Tentei usar o `dplyr` para selecionar os elementos da coluna `x` igual a variável global `x`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(x == x))
```

Mas recebi todo o `data.frame` na resposta. O filtro deve estar considerando apenas a coluna, imagino.

Como indico para o `filter` que um dos `x` é uma variável global?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize `.GlobalEnv$x`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(x == .GlobalEnv$x)

   x  y
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  0  3
4  0  4
5  0  5
6  0  6
7  0  7
8  0  8
9  0  9
10 0 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Com o auxílio do `dplyr` também é possível utilizar o operador `!!` ou a função `UQ`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(x == UQ(x))
```

Ou

```
df %>% filter(x == !!(x))
```

Esta operação "indica ao R" que o primeiro passo a ser realizado no código é a avaliação do `x`.

Fonte: [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1/topics/quasiquotation)